# Add html attribute if the input value meet requirements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let say I have two input. 
When I key-in value in input1 for example 0.4 and meets the requirement then the input2 will remove the readonly attribute. Meanwhile if I input value in input1 is 0.3 then the input2 attribute will become readonly again.

It doesnt work. Maybe i missed out anything here

```js
$(".input1").keydown(function() {
    var dInput = $(this).val();
    if (dInput >= 0.4 && dInput <= 0.6) {
        $(".input2").attr('readonly', true);
    } else {
        $(".input2").removeAttr("readonly");
    }
});

function isNumberKey(e) { // stub
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="input1" name="input1" value="" />

<input type="text" class="input2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="input2" name="input2" value="" readonly />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Use `keyup` function, as the value fills up in a field later and you are trying to capture at `keydown`

2: I have switched the if and else block statements as per your description. Your original code contradicts what you are saying here.

```js
        $(".input1").keyup(function() {

            var dInput = $(this).val();
            if(dInput >= 0.4 && dInput <= 0.6)
            {
                $(".input2").removeAttr("readonly");
            }
            else
            {
                $(".input2").attr('readonly',true);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input1" o id="input1" name="input1" value="" />

<input type="text" class="input2"  id="input2" name="input2" value="" readonly />
```

Comment: yes i tested both. My original jquery is using keyup then by chance i try the keydown as well. and both doesnt works

Comment: @parkway notice I have removed `onkeypress` from html input fields, also the updated code, Try doing `Run snippet` here.

Comment: @parkway did you tried ? hope this will be what you need :)

Comment: wait when i use your copy it works. then when i try to applied using my original one it doesnt works

Comment: @parkway yes, it is because point #2, see in my answer. Now everyone is changing their answer as per this :)

Comment: my mistake. my div class is using same class name as input and it cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the attribute in the wrong condition. I also prefer [***`input`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead of *keydown* here:

```js
$(".input1").on('input', function() {
    var dInput = $(this).val();
    if(dInput >= 0.4 && dInput <= 0.6){
      $(".input2").removeAttr("readonly");
    }
    else{
      $(".input2").attr('readonly', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input1"  id="input1" name="input1" value="" />

<input type="text" class="input2" id="input2" name="input2" value="" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

use **keyup**

```js
function isNumberKey(e){
}

   $(".input1").keyup(function() {

            var dInput = $(this).val();
            dInput = parseFloat(dInput);
            console.log(dInput);
            if(dInput >= 0.4 && dInput <= 0.6)
            {
                $(".input2").attr('readonly',true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(".input2").removeAttr("readonly");
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="input1" name="input1" value="" />

<input type="text" class="input2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="input2" name="input2" value="" readonly />
```

Comment: yes i tested both. My original jquery is using keyup then by chance i try the keydown as well. and both doesnt works... I tried to input 0.3 in input1, but when i pressed 0, the input2 remove the readonly attribute